# How to connect to WiFi on Qubes OS?

Tags: wifi, qubes

I've just installed Qubes OS on my computer. 
There's no WiFi Connection.
I use Lenovo Ideapad 310 ISK.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Many Lenovos are made without a hardware switch and have issues with `rfkill list` showing that wireless is blocked.  The usual fix is to

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist ideapad-laptop" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot

Comment: It's written: "No such file or Directory". Is there another way?

Comment: @NEven did you run the command in sys-net?